# Listing and picking contacts with email ids

Tags: android

The following code fails only on Sony devices. I tried it on Sony Xperia SL and it failed. It works fine on nexus 5:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

It says `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=content://com.android.contacts/data/emails }`

What could be the issue? What are the alternatives? I don't want to create a new activity to list down the contacts with email. I want to show it in the available contact app.

Comment: what is wrong with sony? Hasn't anyone faced the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the action in your intent constructor to Intent. ACTION_GET_CONTENT . I think this is coming because Sony provides his own Contact app and may be the action you are passing in the intent is not used in any of the activities in Contact app .

Comment: this doesn't work. It lists me all set of apps to do the task but not contacts. I think its more of a file picker usage.